# Renaming file name in asset folder dynamically

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have database(say x.db) stored in asset folder(path = "\app\src\main\assets"). I am trying to change its name before it is loaded in runtime but for some reason, I am unable to do so. My goal is to rename the database per user. So if there is 3 user I want to have 3 new databases plus the initial database. 
My code snipped when it runs for the first time,

```
    try {
        File oldFile = new File("\\app\\src\\main\\assets");
        File[] listOfFiles = oldFile.listFiles();//this is always empty.
        for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles) {
            if (listOfFile.isFile() && listOfFile.getName().equals("x.db")) {
                return listOfFile.renameTo(new File("y" + ".db"));
            }
        }
        return false;          
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You can't rename it. Instead, you should copy the file from assets to your local directory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21250573/2894324

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is to rename the database per user.

Then you do not need to rename the asset file, which you cannot as it's part of the APK and thus protected. What you do is copy the asset into the the location where the database is to be stored using the database name that you require per user.

## Example

The following example creates 3 databases copying them from the single asset (mydb in this case). The core code is what is termed as the DatabaseHelper (a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper). Typically this is written to be constructed from just the Context. In this case the user name is passed thus allowing seperate database per user. The database name being the user name suffixed by the asset name.

The database helper **MultiUserDBHelper.java** :-

```
public class MultiUserDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String ASSET_NAME = "mydb";
    public String DB_PATH;

    Context mContext;
    SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;

    public MultiUserDBHelper(Context context, String User) {

        super(context, User+ASSET_NAME, null, 1);
        DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(User+ASSET_NAME).getPath();
        this.mContext = context;
        if (!checkDataBase()) {
            copyDataBase();
        }
        mDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase(); //Forces open and therefore creation if db doesn exist.
    }


    public void copyDataBase() {
        try {
            InputStream myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(ASSET_NAME);
            String outputFileName = DB_PATH;
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0)
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);

            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
            ;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Error copying database from asset");
        }
    }


    public boolean checkDataBase() {
        File dbfile = new File(DB_PATH);
        if (dbfile.exists()) return true;
        if (!(dbfile.getParentFile()).exists()) dbfile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

An Activity that demonstrates use of the above for 3 users :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MultiUserDBHelper dbuser1, dbuser2, dbuser3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbuser1 = new MultiUserDBHelper(this,"User1");
        dbuser2 = new MultiUserDBHelper(this,"User2");
        dbuser3 = new MultiUserDBHelper(this,"User3"); 
    }
}
```

- Obviously you would introduce a methodlogy for selecting/switching users. The abve is intended only to demonstrate the copying/access to each individual database.

After running the above Device Explorer has :-

[image]